# Is there equivalent to settimeofday in Java ?

Tags: java

I'm using Linux.
In C, when I needed to update the date & time I used the function:
`settimeofday` which got `timeval` structure.

Is there equivalent in Java ?
I have the time in milliseconds (from 1970) and I want to set it (as simple as possible).
(I want to avoid the calculation of year/month/day/hour/min/second while using `SimpleDataFormat`.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to setup the date and time information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Calendar` as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   // create a calendar
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // get the time in milliseconds
   System.out.println("Current time is :" + cal.getTime());

   // set time to 5000 ms after january 1 1970
   cal.setTimeInMillis(5000);

   // print the new time
   System.out.println("After setting Time:  " + cal.getTime());
   }
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java can use a `long` for the time in ms after 1970.

Java 8 can use, what is called a [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html), to fake a time other than the real time. Useful for tests: [`now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-) instead of simply `LocalDateTime.now()`.

AFAIK there is not function to correct the system clock itself, for the entire operating system.

You might look whether time servers might be integrated instead, **SNTP, NTP**.

Comment: To clarify, if the purpose behind the Question is needing fake date-time values for testing, then explore the `Clock` class. Various static methods produce `Clock` objects with altered behavior, which you can pass as argument to the various other date-time classes. The altered behaviors include returning a [specific fixed (unchanging) moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-), returning a true moment except shifted by some amount of time, and returning a true time but incrementing by whole seconds or whole minutes etc.